# Background-image not appearing on web site

Tags: html, css, image

Ok, so this is weird.

I am trying to setup social media links to my different fb/youtube/yelp pages.

There is one button that is not showing up and I've tried everything. It's not an issue with the url to the image, as it is the exact same path/type of image as the other buttons that show up. For some reason this image just will not show up and I've tried different images, I've tried converting to different formats, and I've even pointed it to the same image that the other button is using which is showing up fine for the other button but not for the one I'm trying to fix.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="facebookbutton"><a href="#" target="_blank" ></a></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#facebookbutton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(images/fb_button.png);
}

#facebookbutton a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

The code is the exact same as the yelp button I have which is working fine.

I tried pointing the background-image url to the yelp button which is working to see if the image itself was having issues, but it didn't show up with the yelp button in the URL either.

I have no idea why this is happening and am hoping someone has ran into this issue before and might have an idea of why I'm getting this weird issue.

Thank you,
Dan.

Comment: I tried out your code (with my own image) and it works fine.  Are there other CSS rules that could be over-riding the two CSS rules that you posted?

Comment: @MarcAudet yes the code does work i have posted jsbin demo

Comment: Not that I can see but it has to be something like that. I literally copy and pasted the background-image line from the yelp button (which is working fine) to the facebook button and it still doesn't show the yelp image either. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Just curious, if you add some text to the link (`<a>abcd</a>`), can you see the link?

Comment: Your have no quotes around the image URL

Comment: I don't have quotes around any of the buttons that are working either. Adding quotes doesn't change anything. 

@MarcAudet I don't need to add text to see the link, I can add a background color and it will show the background color, and even if I don't I can still click the empty gap where the button is. It's just the background.

Comment: @Druzion quotes are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#facebookbutton {
  width: 56px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/australianlaborparty/pages/2601/attachments/original/1423709665/FB_Button.png?1423709665");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#facebookbutton a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebookbutton">
  <a href="#" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Maybe an error with your image URL

```
#facebookbutton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url("images/fb_button.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeato: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Nope :( 

Doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/gulupulahe/edit?html,css,output)

```
#facebookbutton {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeato: no-repeat;
}

#facebookbutton a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different export format in Photoshop and it worked now. Good to go.